# .hgignore per branch in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Is it possible to have a branch-specific ignore file in mercurial?

It would be handy to have dependencies included in a `production` branch, but not in a development branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial always uses the checked out .hgignore file. So technically you can have different .hgignore files on different branches, but when you use this scheme, you need to take care that they stay different when you merge between this branches.

When you have only one system where the additional ignore patterns should apply, you can also specify an additional igore file within .hg/hgrc via the ui.ignore setting.

```
$ cat >> .hg/hgrc << EOF
[ui]
ignore=.hg/production_ignore
EOF
$ cat > .hg/production_ignore << EOF
# example ignore file, uses the same syntax as .hgignore
syntax: glob
*.swp
*.~
EOF
```

Comment: what is "production_ignore" in this case? Is it a branch name?

Comment: @YuriS This is the name of a local file with additional ignore patterns (in this case .hg/production_ignore). It is a workaround, since there are no branch-specific ignore patterns.